# ¿Como pasar este objeto a json en javascript (angular)?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Hola a todos me han solicitado enviar unos datos en formato json como este:

```
{
"Informacion": {
"str_nombre": "Mario velez",
"str_telefono": "30444441"
},
"Modalidades": {
"int_modalidad": 1
},
"Adicionales": [
{
"int_codigo": 111,
"str_valor": "1"
}
]
}
```

al momento de traer los datos vienen como objetos y por separado:

```
Informacion: [{str_nombre: "Mario velez", str_telefono: "30444441"}]
Modalidades: [{int_modalidad: 1}]
Adicionales: [{int_codigo: 60, str_valor: "1 "}]
```

asi que los uní de esta manera:

```
const params = 'Informacion=' +JSON.stringify(Informacion)+'Modalidades=' + JSON.stringify(Modalidades)+'Adicionales=' + JSON.stringify(Adicionales);

console.log(params);
```

pero al momento de ver lo que imprime por consola sale de esta forma:

```
{,…}
Informacion:" 
[{"str_nombre":"mario velez","str_telefono":"30444441"}]Modalidades=[{"int_modalidad": 1}]Adicionales= 
[{"int_codigo":111,"str_valor":"1"}]"
```

¿Cómo hago para que imprima como lo solicitado?.

Answer (score 0):

Sí todos son objetos js no necesitas usar `stringify` solo crea un nuevo objeto que contenga los anteriores.

El siguiente código asume que `objeto1` y `objeto2` son arreglos de objetos, como el ejemplo que proporcionas:

```js
var objeto1 = [{
  propiedad1 : "valor",
  propiedad2: "valor"
}]

var objeto2 = [{
  propiedad1 : "valor",
  propiedad2 : "valor"
}]

var objetosUnidos = {

objeto1: objeto1[0],
objeto2: objeto2[0]

}


console.log(objetosUnidos);

console.log(JSON.stringify(objetosUnidos));
```